# Calculating solar radiation toward earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, power

This problem is from the book by Arthur Beiser, Concepts of Modern Physics, example 1.7.

> Solar energy reaches the earth at the rate of about $1.4$ kW per square meter of surface perpendicular
>   to the direction of the sun. By how much does the mass of the sun decrease
>   per second owing to this energy loss? The mean radius of the earth’s orbit is $1.5 \times 10^{11}$ m.

The solution provided by the book uses the following

$$P=\frac{P}{A}\times A = \frac{P}{A}\times 4\pi r^2=(1.4\ \text{kW})\times 4\pi (R_{\text{earth}})^2$$

Once we get the power, one can simply convert that amount of energy loss per time into mass loss per time, through the identity $m=E/c^2$.

But since Earth only gets solar radiation on its half of the surface, the area has to be $A=2\pi r^2$, isn't it?

Why one should use a full area of the Earth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that value you are given in the question for $R_{earth}$ is the radius of the Earth's *orbit*, not the radius of the Earth itself. The expression $\frac P A \times 4 \pi r^2$ is calculating the power radiated by the sun across the area of a sphere as large as the Earth's whole orbit, not just the area of the Earth.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just totally misunderstood.